# finding large primes

Tags: elementary-number-theory, soft-question

I was wondering if anyone proved about a specific a number that it has to have a prime factor bigger than the currently largest known prime, without specifying how to find this factor, would it be an interesting result, or a boring one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $p$ be the largest known prime. $p!+1$ has the desired property. I'd categorize this as a boring result.

If you were to replace $p!+1$ by something else, the theorem might be quite interesting. It would depend on the theorem itself, of course.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what has been proven :-P

Generally it is not absolutely necessary to provide an example of an object, if you can assure it exists (and since there are infitely many primes, we have not this problem)

But it really depends on the nature of the theorem..